# Do linux kernel developers use classes?

Tags: c, linux

Recently I have found the following piece of code in the linux kernel tree, commit adfa0fa1dd3cdbccec9597fe53b6177a9aa6e20f2f8; linux/kernel/sched/deadline.c; at the very bottom there is a construct which is pasted below. Please tell me is this some syntax to represent a class, and which compiler do I use to have the code compiled?

```c
{
    .next           = &rt_sched_class,
    .enqueue_task       = enqueue_task_dl,
    .dequeue_task       = dequeue_task_dl,
    .yield_task     = yield_task_dl,

    .check_preempt_curr = check_preempt_curr_dl,

    .pick_next_task     = pick_next_task_dl,
    .put_prev_task      = put_prev_task_dl,

     #ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    .select_task_rq     = select_task_rq_dl,
    .set_cpus_allowed       = set_cpus_allowed_dl,
    .rq_online              = rq_online_dl,
    .rq_offline             = rq_offline_dl,
    .pre_schedule       = pre_schedule_dl,
    .post_schedule      = post_schedule_dl,
    .task_woken     = task_woken_dl,
     #endif

    .set_curr_task      = set_curr_task_dl,
    .task_tick      = task_tick_dl,
    .task_fork              = task_fork_dl,
    .task_dead      = task_dead_dl,

    .prio_changed           = prio_changed_dl,
    .switched_from      = switched_from_dl,
    .switched_to        = switched_to_dl,
}
```

Comment: Yeap, I see now, thanks, why don't u write an answer? I would mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is a normal [structure initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) using *designated initializers*.

The Linux kernel is almost all plain C, but often uses GCC-specific extensions. Designated initializers is not an extension, they are a plain standard C feature and was introduced in the C99 standard.

Answer (score 3):

Class is a term applicable to C++, not C. What you see is a struct, initialized via [designators](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Linux Kernel is written in C (mostly) and is buildable with GCC compiler.

Comment: What in the Kernel is not written in C?

Comment: Some parts are written in assembly. `find -name "*.S" | wc -l` on current master tip gives me following output: `1335`.